# Laravel - Issue with daily Revenue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the daily, weekly, monthly , yearly and overall revenue using the query below:

```
$revenues = DB::table("vw_revenue_report")
->select(
    "vw_revenue_report.channel",
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN amount ELSE 0 END) daily_revenue"),    
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN amount ELSE 0 END) weekly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN amount ELSE 0 END) monthly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN amount ELSE 0 END) yearly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(vw_revenue_report.amount) total_revenue")
)
->groupBy("vw_revenue_report.channel")
->orderByRaw('vw_revenue_report.channel ASC')
->get();
```

I have issue with:

> DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN created_at = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN amount ELSE 0 END) daily_revenue")

deally, it should return the revenue for the current day.  Its not giving me the required result. Its just displaying 0

**Note:**
1. created_at is in datetime format

2. It should group by channel

Comment: You should use >= with INTERVAL 1 DAY or use = & remove INTERVAL 1 DAY.

Comment: When I used  >= with NTERVAL 1 DAY or use = & remove NTERVAL 1 DAY.,  i still got 0.   and there are today's data in the table

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are using a direct comparison `=` in `... created_at = NOW() ...`, instead of `>=`. So you will only match revenue report records that were created exactly 24 hours ago.